# Changing the type of a payload

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have created the following type for my Http module:

```
export type HttpPromise<TData> = Promise<HttpPromiseSuccess<TData>>
export type HttpPromiseSuccess<TData> = {
    config: object;
    headers: object;
    request: XMLHttpRequest;
    status: number;
    statusText: string;
    data: TData;
}
```

Let's say I have the following two types:

```
export type User = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    ...
}
export type ApiError = {
    error: string;
    statusCode: number;
}
```

I would normally do:

```
const promise: HttpPromise<User> = Http.get('/api/users/1');
promise
   .then(response => {
      // response.data is now of type `User`    
   });
```

But my API could actually return the error type `ApiError` so I want the `response.data` to be of either type `User` or of type `ApiError`. I tried

```
const promise: HttpPromise<User | ApiError> = Http.get('/api/users/1');
// But now response.data only contains the union of the two type
```

I also tried to do

```
const promise: HttpPromise<User> = Http.get('/api/users/1');
promise
   .then(response => {
       if ('error' in response.data) {
           const payload = response.data as ApiError;
       }
   });
```

But this cannot do the casting. What are my options? Unfortunately I do not have control over the API; the API will always return a `200` but if the payload contains `error`, then it will have a `statusCode` that contains the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [user defined typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

The typeguard itself looks like this:

```
const isError = <T>(response: T | ApiError): response is ApiError => {
    return !!(response as ApiError).data.error;
};
```

This will return a boolean - true if response is an Error, or false if it is not.  Your request handler can then be:

```
const promise: HttpPromise<User | ApiError> = Http.get('/api/users/1');
promise
    .then(response => {
        if (isError(response)) {
            // response typed as ApiError  
        } else {
            // response typed as User
        }
    });
```

Because the typeguard is generic, then this will also work with other response types:

```
const promise: HttpPromise<BlogPost | ApiError> = Http.get('/api/users/1');
promise
    .then(response => {
        if (isError(response)) {
            // response typed as ApiError  
        } else {
            // response typed as BlogPost
        }
    });
```